# In Git, how to push different versions of files to different remotes?

Tags: git

In Git, how to push different versions of files to different remotes?

I have two remotes `origin` and `public`.  I'd like to always push the latest version of files to `origin` which is an internal development server, and a different version of files, which are often older and checked for errors to `public` which is a place for publishing the deployable version of my code.  How to do this in Git?  If I have multiple `public` servers such as `p1`, `p2`, how to publish different versions to those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want is different branches.  Most people do their main development on the master branch (the default) and then create a branch whenever they do a release.  Bug fixes happen on the release branch (and are later merged to master), while ongoing development happens on master.  Deploying a new release is just a matter of checking out the release branch.

You can push all your branches to all remotes, or just push some of the branches to different remotes.

See the chapter on [Basic Branching & Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) in the Git Book.